# Python code to create a list containing comma separated string and int enclosed in parentheses?

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have a snippet of python code that is taking data from a row in a database table and turning it into a list.  I am getting 2 string fields from the table.  I want to turn it into a list that looks like this:

```
a_list = [('Tom', 23), ('Dick', 45), ('Harry', 33)]
```

so given:

```
name = 'Tom'
age = '23'
```

I am trying to concatenate the items like so:

```
nextItem = "("+name+","+int(age)+")'
```

The code errors out saying you cannot concatenate a str and an int data type.

Can someone provide the code that will do what I need?

Comment: `a_list.append((name,int(age)))`

Comment: "("+name+","+str(age)+")"
I think you cannot concatenate a string and a integer

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want a string that looks like `"('Tom', 23)"`? Or do you want an actual tuple that contains two elements?

Comment: or "({0} ,{1})".format(name,age)

Comment: they are both strings already, if you want one value as an int and the other a string you cannot concat .

Comment: I guess it is a tuple.  I am new to python.  I do not want a string value.  I want it to look just like the list at the top NOT "('Tom', 23)".

Comment: you can extract them all in a list comprehension storing name and age in tuples and casting age to an int, how do you extract name and age?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store name as string and age as number you can do this

```
a_list.append((name,int(age)))
```

If you want both of them be strings you can just `format` them

```
a_list.append("{},{}".format(name,age)
```

or concatenate them using the following syntax

```
a_list.append("("+name+","+str(age)+")")
```

*But* the first variant might be the best among these.

All in all, you *cannot concatenate integer and string*!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
nextItem = "("+name+","+int(age)+")'
```

where you cannot concatenate strings to an integer, you can format the string nicely:

```
nextItem = '({},{})'.format(name, age)
```

But if you want to get this list of tuples:

```
a_list = [('Tom', 23), ('Dick', 45), ('Harry', 33)]
```

you have to keep `age` an integer:

```
a_list.append((name, age))
```

Answer (score 0):

To print each variables according to its data type you can format the string as following:

```
print "name : %s age : %d " % (name, age)
```

If you need to create a list use:

```
nameagelist.append((name, age))
```

assuming age is an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension replacing whatever with whatever you are getting name and age from:

```
a_list = [(name,int(age)) for name,age in whatever]
```